# Android: notifyDataSetChanged is called but ListView not updated

Tags: android, android-listview

I got this ListView which is populated from a JSON data on the web. But when I updated the JSON entry, for example adding a new entry the ListView isn't updated. It doesn't show the new entry on the list even though I've already called the notifyDataSetChanged().

Here's my code:

```
public class ProjectsList extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.projects_list);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LooserSync.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstText);
        MySimpleCursorAdapter projectAdapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitems,
                managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                        Database.Project.NAME), new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
                        Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE, Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE }, null, null,
                        null), new String[] { Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE, Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.txt_title, R.id.image });
        listView.setAdapter(projectAdapter);
        projectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              

                Intent i = new Intent(ProjectsList.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                i.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long
                        .toString(id)));
                i.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position",position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            loader = new ImageLoaderCache(context);
            this.context = context;
        }
        Activity activity= ProjectsList.this;
        Context context=null;
        ImageLoaderCache loader = null;

        public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
            v.setTag(value);
            loader.displayImage(value, activity, v);
        }
    }


}
```

**UPDATED here's the LooserSync.java**

```
public class LooserSync extends IntentService {

    public LooserSync() {
        super("LooserSyncService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Database.OpenHelper dbhelper = new Database.OpenHelper(getBaseContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        db.beginTransaction();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
                "http://liebenwald.spendino.net/admanager/dev/android/projects.json");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        instream), 8000);
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
                instream.close();
                String bufstring = total.toString();
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(bufstring);
                Database.Tables tab = Database.Tables.AllTables.get(Database.Project.NAME);
                tab.DeleteAll(db);
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    tab.InsertJSON(db, (JSONObject) arr.get(i));
                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: you forgot 'getContentResolver().notifyChange(   Uri.withAppendedPath(LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), null);' from my last sample there is a menu called sync to show how to refresh data

Comment: So I set this, 'listView.setAdapter(projectAdapter);
  getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.withAppendedPath(LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), null);' but still I don't know why the new entry on my list isn't read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using a cursor to populate the list you have to get a new one or requery the old one  after you changed (add, edit or remove) something on your model.

When you got a new cursor you can pass it to the adapter by calling [changeCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29).

**UPDATE**

Following code will get a new cursor each time onResume() called. So your list should be up to date. Of course changes on the model which are made while the list is shown are not updated to the list. If you want a live update of the list you have to implement some kind of observer pattern. So your activity would get notified when the model changed.

```
public class ProjectsList extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.projects_list);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LooserSync.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstText);

        final String[] from = new String[] { Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE, Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE };
        final int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txt_title, R.id.image};

        MySimpleCursorAdapter projectAdapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitems, null, from, to);

        listView.setAdapter(projectAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              

                Intent i = new Intent(ProjectsList.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                i.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long
                        .toString(id)));
                i.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position",position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    public void onResume(){
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                        Database.Project.NAME), new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
                        Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE, Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE }, null, null, null);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstText);                         
        ((CursorAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor);
    }
```

Comment: Yes but can you first tell me where the update of the data happens, then I can tell you where you should get a new Cursor or requery the old one.

Comment: I think it's here  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LooserSync.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);, I've just updated my question. Please have a look. Thx

Comment: Ok you use a service. But how is the control flow? Could the model change at any time or only outside of the ProjectsList activity? The best way is to query and bind the cursor to the adapter in the onResume() method, so you'll get updated data every time onResume() is updated.

Comment: Ok,can you provide me an example with my code above? That would be very helpful and clear :)

Comment: Thanks much, but I wonder why I got an error on this line:  ((CursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor);

Comment: method getListAdapter is undefined for the type ProjectsList, CursorAdapter cannot be resolved as a type. I'm using android API 7 anyway (2.1)

Comment: Updated my answer check the onResume() method. I thought you are using a ListActiviy.

Comment: No error but I have to declare the listView as the global variable but it causesn the app crashed everytime I run it, since it gives null pointer. Whereas the R.id.lstText belongs to the projects_list layout

Comment: I'm confused, does R.id.lstText reference a ListView or something else?

Comment: yes R.id.lstText references a ListView, but I declared it inside the onCreate that's why on onResume the variable isn't readable

Comment: Yes, but is a local variable to onCreate(), so you can also declare it as a local variable in onResume().

Comment: Yes I know, so I declared these lines inside the onResume "ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstText);
        ((MySimpleCursorAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor);" but the app is crashed because of the nullpointer exception. Can you imagine?

Comment: I suggest you debug your code to see where the exception occurs.

Comment: So here's the stacktrace. 05-27 08:10:36.596: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 08:10:36.596: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at spendino.de.ProjectsList.onResume(ProjectsList.java:71)
---> Line 71: ((MySimpleCursorAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor);and then I debug it with System.out.println(listView);System.out.println(cursor); the result is nothing is null: 05-27 08:10:36.538: INFO/System.out(380): android.widget.ListView@44f3bde8
05-27 08:10:36.546: INFO/System.out(380): android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@44f20ed8

Comment: Try to split the line ((MySimpleCursorAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor); in single instructions so you can check each statement.

Comment: MySimpleCursorAdapter adapter = (MySimpleCursorAdapter)listView.GetAdapter();   adapter.changeCursor(cursor);

Comment: aha, found out the problem is here: adapter.changeCursor(cursor); it must be with the cursor..any idea what I have to do with it?

Comment: Mh hard to say. Ok adapter and cursor are not null? Then something might get wrong within the adapter. Are you sure, that the method you call to get the cursor is correct?

Answer (score 0):

`projectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

replace the above line with the given blow line then you got solution of your problem.

`((MySimpleCursorAdapter)(ProjectsList.listView.getAdapter())).notifyDataSetChanged();`

Mistake: You should get adapter of the list view after that you notify the adapter of the list.

Comment: Ok plese give the any event for notifying adapter like OnClick event or any other event  and put it line with in the event and remove form there.

Comment: I really don't get what you mean, can you provide me a code for solution instead? Thx